# what data transformation function will reverse the order in the original data?

Tags: data-transformation

I want to apply a data transformation function that produces value between 0 and 1 and also the order is reversed. The max becomes min after transformation and the minimum becomes max value.

Assuming the presence of zero in the original data and i want to preserve the median what are the data transformation functions that i can look at?

Comment: There are any number of transformations that can do this. How are we to decide which one is "best" for your needs? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: After transforming into $[0,1]$ to produce a value $z,$ compute $1-z.$  That reduces your question to "what is the best order-preserving transformation for my data"?  It needs more details to be answerable.

Comment: i think 1-z will work. Modified the question to know about what are all the data tranformation functions i can look at

Comment: What does it mean to "preserve the median"? Any injective transformation of your data will have a median that corresponds to a median of the original data.

Comment: @Sycorax Instead of "injective" I believe you mean "strictly increasing."  Generally, quantiles are not otherwise equivariant under bijections.

Comment: @whuber Yes, thank you. I was in a hurry. But does it need to be *strictly increasing* or is merely order-preserving injection necessary for the specific case of a median? For instance, negating the data has a median that’s the negation of the original median.

Comment: @Sycorax That's a good point. I agree that *strictly order preserving or reversing* is the most general requirement to assure equivariance of medians.  That is because the median is a special quantile: no other quantile is equivariant under a strictly order-reversing transformation.

Comment: @whuber I agree! This is what tripped me up initially -- I realized that for a median specifically, the transformation didn't have to be strictly *increasing*, but I deleted "increasing" instead of adding "order-preserving." Sloppy of me!

Comment: i have been googling for the meanings of "injective transformation" and "bijections". Any recommendations for where i can learn more about these?